# Firebase Real-time DB Security Rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

when users are banned from the room, I want to remove these users read & write permission on security rules. Btw: I added the user id into the room for the check this user is banned.

Security Rules;

```
{
  "rules": {
    "live": {
        "rooms": {
          "$room": {
              ".write": "!$room.child('auth.uid').exists()", // auth.uid from Fb Auth
              ".read": "!$room.child('auth.uid').exists()",
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Real-time database data

```
{
  "live" : {
    "rooms" : {
      "1245" : { // room id
        "14Kq4sx2X07FbNhOVBxQcYM3TZ8X53" : -1, // banned user uid from Auth
        "comments" : [ {
          "comment" : "hello",
          "date" : "2020-12-20 20:23:33",
          "uid" : "14Kq4sx2X07FbNhOVBxQcYM3TZ8X53",
          "username" : "name"
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But these rules are not working, when I added auth id into the room but every user can read & write this room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quotes around `'auth.uid'`, which means the rules check for that literal string: `'auth.uid'`. If you want to check agains the value of `auth.uid` you should not put it in quotes.

So:

```
".write": "!data.child(auth.uid).exists()",
```

Comment: I can't save this changes, but I changed this code block as ".write": "!data.child(auth.uid).exists()", and now working, thanks 

Comment: Good catch, I had indeed overlooked that second mistake. Glad to see you got it working! 